# How to hide some keys on your object when using console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, javascript-objects, console.log

Okay, I'm fairly new to javascript and node so this question might sound stupid to you, but I really need an enlightenment. Anyway, I have an object that I got from my mongoose. Let's make an example

```
Model.findOne({name:'John'}).exec(function (err, data){
 console.log(data);
});
```

So, when I console.loged the **data** the result was

> { _id: 613614asdfa6115,
>     name: 'John',
>     __v: 0 }

Then, I had a stupid idea to add another key to that object, so, as a normal javascript noob would do, I add another key to the data:

> data.hello = 'hi'

**BUT**, when I try to console.log the **data** the result was still the same. I was so baffled. So I used the [lodash clone](https://lodash.com/docs#clone) to clone the object; to my surprise there were a lot of hidden keys that the first console.log did not get.

Here is the result of the cloned object: http://pastebin.com/zE71Fg2H

My question is: How did they hide some of the keys from the console.log?

Comment: Really!??! a negative vote without a reason?! Don't I deserve an explanation?

Comment: These "hidden keys" are just keys labeled non-enumerable or from the prototype of the object. That is all.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Now I know how much I don't know about javascript yet. But seriously, does my question really needs a downvote? It was an honest question.

Comment: I think your question got downvoted because the down-voter felt that your question didn't need answering or was just ignorant. Sorry, but the Stack Overflow community can be harsh sometimes.

Comment: Yeah, figures. Just because they have enough reputation does not mean they can just downvote without prior explanation/notice. I mean, how can the OP know what he did wrong when all he/she gets is a downvote? If this is a duplicate question, at least I get a link to that question. Anyway, thank you very much for enlightening me kind sir. If you can post your answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2):

try this -

```
Model.findOne({name:'John'}).exec(function (err, data){
 data = data.toObject();
 data.hello = 'hi'
 console.log(data);
});
```

I hope it will work. [For more information use this link.](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject)

Comment: Very insightful, but this does not really answer my question though. But I'll upvote it. Thank you!

Comment: after saving the document mongoose return the JSON object. if you want to modify those property you need to convert the JSON object to javascript object.you can do that by using toObject method.